# Astrology for only normal humans not for disabled persons and animals in the earth

Tags: astrology

I read some astrology article's and they said astrology results and outputs are not for disabled persons and animals. Is it true? And if its true any reference is there in the astrology.

Comment: Its for all humans.....

Comment: @RakeshJoshi: References need...!

Answer (score 2):

Astrology applies to all living beings.
Kalyana Varmas Saravali, Chapter 2, Meaning of Hora
1-5. The Creator Brahma has written on the foreheads of all living beings their fates,...